# Generating digital certificates using Bouncycastle

Tags: java, cryptography, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have determined, after some research, that in order to generate and sign certificates programmatically in java I need the bouncycastle library.

Unfortunately it appears that the library has gone through a major overhaul sometime fairly recently. A great deal of their classes are now deprecated and all of the tutorials and code samples I can find that are simple enough to understand are deprecated along with them.

I am reasonably new to cryptography. Armed with only basic knowledge and fuzzy idea of what I'm actually trying to accomplish, I've fumbled through the out of date tutorials and the assumed-knowledge Bouncycastle documentation, and its been an arduous experience.

Are there any simple to understand, up to date Bouncycastle tutorials, or alternative libraries I should look at? Or should I grit my teeth, ignore the deprecation warnings and hope for the best?

Comment: That or you could take a look at EJBCA, either at the source code or you could use it as a service. Are you sure you need to generate certificates from code? There are plenty other options of creating cerficates out there.

Comment: Im designing a server which provides authentication to clients so that they can then verify each other in a p2p environment without the requirement for said server to always be available. A different option would be welcome. I will look at EJBCA and comment again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard to find, but the [bouncycastle wiki](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/dashboard.action) has some short but sweet documention. In particular this first example at [this page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs) entitled **A Simple Operator Example** should get you started.

Another perfectly fine alternative is to just use version 1.46 of the library, the last version to use the old api.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to accept. I ended up using 1.46 with the aid of the wiki and online tutorials and once I had a grip on that migrated my code forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use Bouncycastle directly or can't you use it as a Cryptographic Service Provider? So you do not need to use BCs API. See the [JCA Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html). I use for some encryption these lines:

```
static {
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}

public void someMethod() {
  KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
  Key key = fact.generatePublic(PUB_KEY_SPEC);
  // do stuff
}
```

You might take a closer look at  the [`CertificateFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html).

Comment: "This class defines the functionality of a certificate factory, which is used to generate certificate, certification path (CertPath) and certificate revocation list (CRL) objects **from their encodings.**" emphasis mine. Furhtermore, he did not ask how to create a key from its encoding either.