# How to encrypt arbitrary data types using BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

Can anyone show me an example of how to do encryption in Java using BouncyCastle (or similar API) for data types other than `String`?

I want to encrypt other Java types like `Integer`, `Double` and `Date` etc. I've looked over bouncycastle.org but cannot find any documentation of their API.

Comment: Similar issue is here, check it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984610/generating-digital-certificates-using-bouncycastle

Comment: This question at Stackoverflow should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052213/an-example-of-encrypting-an-xml-file-in-java-using-bouncy-castle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption is an operation that is always performed on binary data. Any examples you've seen that work with `String` objects will be converting those strings into byte arrays at some point during the process.

The goal is to define a canonical method of converting your data into a byte array representation. Once you have this, you can use example code found all over the Internet to perform the encryption.

You may wish to convert an `Integer` into a four byte array, for example. Perhaps using code such as:

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(integerValue).array()
```

A `Date` might be best converted to a UNIX timestamp and then converted to a byte array using the code above.

The recipient of your encrypted data must understand how you serialised it to a byte array so that they can reverse the process. Note that in the case of strings, it's important both sides agree on a charset used when converting to/from a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the code which encrypt byte array, hope that might help you in some way. Remember below ENCRYPTION_KEY value can be anything, its totally depends on you.

```
 // Cryptographic algorithm
  private final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
  //
 private final byte[] ENCRYPTION_KEY = new byte[]
 {
        'E', 'r', ';', '|', '<', '@', 'p', 'p', 'l', '1', 'c', '@', 't', '1', '0', 'n'
 };

public byte[] encryptValue(byte[] valueToEnc) throws EncryptionException
{
    try
    {
        // Constructs a secret key from the given byte array and algorithm
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY, ALGORITHM);
        // Creating Cipher object by calling getInstance() factory methods and
        // passing ALGORITHIM VALUE = "AES" which is a 128-bit block cipher
        // supporting keys of 128, 192, and 256 bits.
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // Initialize a Cipher object with Encryption Mode and generated key
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // To encrypt data in a single step, calling doFinal() methods: If we
        // want to encrypt data in multiple steps, then need to call update()
        // methods instead of doFinal()
        byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc);
        // Encrypting value using Apache Base64().encode method
        byte[] encryptedByteValue = new Base64().encode(encValue);

        return encryptedByteValue;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new EncryptionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.